# SQL Server Mirror IP change

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

We have an SQL Server Mirroring established between a database on two SQL Server 2012 Standard instances on two different servers. The witness is on a third server running the express edition. The IP addresses (not hostnames) of primary, mirror and witness servers are mentioned in the mirroring configurations while creating the mirror using SSMS. Now problem is that a change in the IP address of the mirror is required. There is a proper reasoning behind that and it can't be avoided. The system is live and outage should be avoided to the max. The new IP is accessible from both primary and witness.
When we take the mirror server out, the mirroring is affected, but as soon the server is back with the same old IP, mirroring resumes appropriately. However, how to change the endpoints IP address without having the need to remove and then recreate the mirror. Is it possible or there is NO way this can be achieved without remove/recreate?

If there is an absolute need here to do this remove/recreate, how to ensure that we don't copy over the complete database and its logs and redo the process from scratch. If all client's access to the primary is blocked during the time to ensure that no transaction is taking place, would this suffice?

A solution without remove/recreate would be the preferred one.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you use IP addresses in the mirroring setup? Either way, I'd suggest breaking the mirror and setting it up using names rather than IP addresses. From what I remember, this doesn't require downtime at the primary. I'd set it up as asynchronous initially at least until the back log of undelivered log clears.

Comment: @BenThul If mirror gets broken, and somehow a transaction runs at the primary, will the mirror be re-established straightaway or do we need to do one log backup from primary and restore on secondary before the mirror can be re-established.

Comment: You'd do it just like you were establishing it for the first time. So yes, you'd restore a full backup, any log backups to get the mirror up to current, and then set up mirroring. The nice thing is that you need only pause your t-log backups during that last step.

Comment: No not really, but this is why it is most definitely wise to invest in a IP: Mirror and also a Relocator and or a Scrambler for your IP: Address.